# Perforce merge in between two local workspace

Tags: merge, perforce, perforce-client-spec

I am new to perforce .trying to merge files in my local workspace.

I have a file in 2 local workspace workspace1 and workspace2 I want to merge I couldn’t find info to merge workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Submit the files from workspace1.
2. In workspace2 do `p4 sync` (if it maps the same files) or `p4 integrate` (if it maps a different  branch).